# For r.v.'s $Y,Z, X_1, X_2$, if $Z = f(X_1, X_2)$, does $Y\perp Z \mid X_1, X_2$ automatically rule out the possibility of $Y \perp X_2 \mid X_1$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider random variables $Y,Z, X_1, X_2$. Suppose that $Z$ is a measurable function $f$ of both $X_1, X_2$ such that:

$$
Z = f(X_1, X_2)
$$

Then suppose that $Y\perp Z \mid X_1, X_2$. That is, conditional on $(X_1, X_2)$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. I am wodnering if this automatically restricts the possibility of

$$
Y \perp X_2 \mid X_1
$$

It seems to me that intuitively in order for $Y\perp Z \mid X_1, X_2$ to hold, then this must imply $Y$ was a function of both $(X_1, X_2)$ since $Z$ is a function of both $(X_1, X_2)$ and so it seems $Y$ must be a function of both to "obtain" the independence. I am unable to prove it using conditional probabilities, does anyone have any idea how I can go about verifying this? It follows that:

$$
P(Y\mid Z, X_1, X_2) = P(Y \mid X_1, X_2)
$$

and

$$
P(Y \mid X_1, X_2) = P(Y \mid X_1)
$$

but I do not know how to incorporate the fact $Z$ depends on both $X_1, X_2$.

Comment: Any random a variable is independent of $Z$ when conditioned on $X_1$ and $X_2$. So $Y\perp X_2|X_1$ is not ruled out.

Comment: Thank you. For the above to hold where $Y\perp Z \mid X_1, X_2$, would it force $Y$ to be a function of both $X_1, X_2$ if $Z$ were a function of both?

Comment: What @KaviRamaMurthy is saying is that the restriction $Y \perp Z | X_1, X_2$ is no restriction at all, since it is true no matter what $Y$ is.  So $Y$ can be function of both $X_i$, only one of them, none of them, dependent with some $X_i$, independent, etc.

Comment: Thanks, if it were the case that $X_2$ is a function of $X_1$ such that $X_2 = f(X_1)$ for some measurable $f$, would this change anything?